# Can I ,somehow, prevent losing custom templates I made in Bartik Drupal 8 theme?

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, drupal-theming

I had 2 custom templates I used in core/bartik theme which got deleted after I updated drupal core.

Is it possible to "protect" those templates from being deleted?

Comment: never edit or update any templates found in core theme! Instead use the concept of sub theme in drupal. https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/theming/creating-a-sub-theme

Answer (score 0):

Make your own theme. Inherit some existing theme if you don't want to start from scratch. Then copy existing templates to your theme and change them the way you like. Never change Drupal core files, including themes.

By changing core files you made updates almost impossible.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to create your own theme or sub theme from scratch you can make  Bartik to be your own custom theme by just placing coping of to live inside /theme directory.

So now you will have 2 "Bartik" themes
Drupal core's one in

```
/core/themes/bartik
```

and yours in

```
/theme/bartik
```

In this case drupal will use the copy inside /themes/barik

**But**, if doing so, it is highly recommended to go another step and rename your copy of the Bartik to be something like "My Bartik" by

1. Edit the theme name inside bartik.info.yml
2. Perform search/replace in all theme files of "bartik" into "my_bartik" (machine name).
3. Replace "bartik" also in file names.
4. Rename the theme directory to be your new custom name (machine name).